# Superimposing high resolution NetCDF data on Google Earth?

Tags: data, geoprocessing, google-earth, netcdf

I have got output from Weather Research Forecasting Software(WRF) in NETCDF format. These are basically high resolution forecasts for precipitation and wind barbs(sea breeze circulations or slope valley circulations). I want to be able to display this on Google Earth or some similar GIS software. It should be interactive meaning I should be click to the highest possible resolution to tell the viewer in which neighborhood the rainfall occurred. It should also show the terrain etc if in mountainous area. The tools on this web page - http://www.nusculus.com/wtools allows me to see static geographical domain information on Google Earth by converting WRF output(in NETCDF format) into KML format. I want to be able to project meteorological data onto Google Earth. Does anyone know of any tool(could be in any language-java,python) out there that does this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try ncWMS (http://www.resc.rdg.ac.uk/trac/ncWMS/). This project aims to publish netCDF data as WMS services.

Meteorological data on web mapping is always a challenging task due to size and frequency of data available. Solutions will probably involve a mix of server size (http://www.geo-solutions.it/blog/developers-corner-supporting-wind-barbs-geoserver-geotools/) and client side (http://www.asrc.ro/imeteosat_beta/geostationary_view.php) approaches.

Best luck